# Excel: Need to retrieve Date in " yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm" format from string having date and time

Tags: excel

I have column in excel which has values like **"12:00 AM CDT on June 01, 2017"** and I need to convert it into format **2017/06/01 00:00**

Any lead will be appreciated

Comment: Are you want to change the format of cell?  Or want to get the value in VBA?

Comment: No, I want to add new cell in excel which has this converted format "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this, if `CDT on` part of text is constant, is to use this formula in cell `B1`(in case your dates start in cell `A1`) and drag it to the bottom of dates. In `B1` enter `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"CDT on ","")`, After you substituted all text via formula, then you `copy/PasteSpecial value` formulas in same range. Then select whole column with clean dates, go to `Data tab`==>`Text to Columns`==>choose `delimited` type==>press `next` until last question==>there select `date` type and click finish.

Comment: Thanks Kresimir L, this solution helped me.